# executing gcc from notepad++?

Tags: c, gcc, notepad++, compilation

How would I compile a file through notepad++, is there away i can invoke the compiler (gcc) and pass through the file onto gcc?

i have gcc in C:\Program Files\gcc

Answer (score 7):

You can [run external tools](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/run-HOWTO.php) from Notepad++.  You can use something along the lines of the following command for compiling a single source file as an executable using gcc:

```
cmd /K "c:\path\to\gcc.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe"
```

The `cmd /K` keeps the command window around after it executes the command; otherwise it will exit immediately after the `gcc` process completes its task, which isn't helpful if you have build errors.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for single file C programming:
- Install the NppExec plugin, then:

```
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"\$(NAME_PART).exe
```